# Syntax issue adding List to Object

Tags: c#, json

I have class that I created from some JSON data. The JSON data is correct.

```
public class ARCustomers
{
    public ARCustomers()
    {
        CustomerOptionalFieldValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactsFax { get; set; }
    public string ContactsPhone { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int CreditLimitCustomerCurrency { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
    public string OnHold { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PrintStatements { get; set; }
    public string Salesperson1 { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryCode { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfOptionalFields { get; set; }
    public string ProcessCommandCode { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> CustomerOptionalFieldValues { get; set; 
}
```

I'm trying to create a customer object which can have many optional field values. The number is determined by the input data. So it could be no optional field values, or 3, 5, or 100.

So, I have created my customer object:

```
ARCustomers customer = new ARCustomers();
```

I populate it:

```
customer.CustomerNumber = customers.Items[0].custNo;
customer.ShortName = customers.Items[0].custNo;
customer.CustomerName = customers.Items[0].custAddresses[0].name;
... more values filled in ...
```

If I want to add some optional fields, how do I create the optional field object(s), and add them to the customer object?

The idea is that this will be converted into a JSON request and passed to a web api.

To give an indication of the JSON I need to get, here is the structure I'm aiming for:

```
{
  "customerNumber": null,
  "shortName": null,
  "addressLine1": null,
  "addressLine2": null,
  "city": null,
  "contactName": null,
  "contactsFax": null,
  "contactsPhone": null,
  "country": null,
  "creditLimitCustomerCurrency": 0,
  "customerName": null,
  "email": null,
  "faxNumber": null,
  "groupCode": null,
  "onHold": null,
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "printStatements": null,
  "salesperson1": null,
  "startDate": "",
  "stateProvince": null,
  "terms": null,
  "territoryCode": null,
  "zipPostalCode": null,
  "numberOfOptionalFields": 0,
  "processCommandCode": null,
  "customerOptionalFieldValues": [
  {
     "customerNumber": null,
     "optionalField": null,
     "value": null
  },
  {
     "customerNumber": null,
     "optionalField": null,
     "value": null
  }]
}
```

Comment: hi @snert, do u mean to have an object which will hold optional fields dynamically ? for example if the json contains 3 optional fields the object should contain 3 as well and so on ?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class code became this:

```
public class COFXCompanyNumber
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string OptionalField { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ARCustomers
{
    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string ContactsFax { get; set; }
    public string ContactsPhone { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int CreditLimitCustomerCurrency { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FaxNumber { get; set; }
    public string GroupCode { get; set; }
    public string OnHold { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string PrintStatements { get; set; }
    public string Salesperson1 { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
    public string Terms { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryCode { get; set; }
    public string ZipPostalCode { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfOptionalFields { get; set; }
    public string ProcessCommandCode { get; set; }
    public IList<COFXCompanyNumber> CustomerOptionalFieldValues { get; set; }
}
```

Adding the optional fields this way puts them into a collection that the target system seems to like. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to replace this `CustomerOptionalFieldValue` with a dictionary which has as a key the name of the property and holds the values of that property.

```
public class ARCustomers
{
    public ARCustomers()
    {
         CustomerOptionalFieldValues = new Dinctionary<string, object>();
    }

    public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    .....
    public Dictionary<string, object> CustomerOptionalFieldValues { get; set; }

}
```

Then you can enter optional values in this dictionary:

```
ARCustomers arCustomers = new ARCustomers();
arCustomers.CustomerOptionalFieldValues.Add("customerNumber", null);
arCustomers.CustomerOptionalFieldValues.Add("optionalField", 1);
....
```

Then its easier to work with the dictionary for the next steps.

EDIT 1:

In that case if you have multiple json data in optional fields you should use `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` instead of `Dictionary<string, object>` like below in the fiddle:

Click [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/E95VnA) to see an example:

Comment: Oh this is almost bang on. When I generate the customer object, I push in the data. I sent it to my function to push into the target system and it serialises it using this: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload). What it misses out in the serialised JSON string is [ and ] to surround the CustomerOptionalFieldValues. The JSON is valid with and without those, but for some reason, the target system I am using, requires the [ and ] around the embedded options. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes sure it can be controlled by json serializer but can u give me an example of using [and] syntax so i can elaborate more

Comment: Oh do u mean to add these [ ] around the custom data fields as u did in the json above ?

Comment: Yes, the customerOptionalFields needs to have [ and ] around the block. So if there are multiple optional fields, there is a single set of square brackets that surround the block.

Comment: I've updated the JSON above to show with multiple optional fields and how the square brackets need to be

Comment: Solved it. Not sure how I can post my code changes without rewriting the question

Comment: if my answer is correct u dont need to post anything. In case you have any difference you can add another answer. If my answer is correct please consider marking it as correct so others do not see it as unsolved question. You can edit existing one if you want